# How do I calculate subtotals using onblur and javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I calculate subtotals for each row of a product listing by using an input text field to enter one of the numbers?

example:

```
colA    colB            colC

100 - [text input] = [calculated result]

880 - [text input] = [calculated result]

720 - [text input] = [calculated result]

130 - [text input] = [calculated result]
...
```

I'm sure this is fairly easy to do with Javascript, but I've looked and can't find a simple answer.  I'm not very familiar with Javascript so I need a simple solution.  Thanks in advance for all the help! :)

Comment: What did you try? What specific issue did you have trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  In the future, you can probably get a good answer faster if you write your question more clearly.

You can use document.getElementById('id_of_text_input').value to get or set the value of any text input.  Note that you are using `id`, not `name`.

You can use `parseFloat` to get a read a string as a floating number value.

In order to attach a function to the onblur event, you can use the `setAttribute` function.

So, for example, if you have a text input with id `colA` and you want to subtract 100 from the value the user enters and save the result in a text input with id `colB`.

You could write code like this:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>    
    <input type='text' id='colA' />
    <input type="text" id='colB' />
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var colA = document.getElementById('colA');
    var colB = document.getElementById('colB');
    colA.setAttribute('onblur',
    function () {
        var value = colA.value;
        var number = parseFloat(value)-100;
        colB.value = number;
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I will advise you to take note that I have passed a *function* as an argument to the method setAttribute.  In case you're not familiar with fact, many modern languages such as C++ and Java do not allow you do to this.  It allows for a different programming methodology known as "functional programming".

Answer (score 0):

Very useful for me. Thanks, Daniel

If you want to calculate a percentage (5% for example) and use Jquery, you have to

```
    $(function(){
        $(".input-valorinicial").blur(function(){
            var valorinicial = document.getElementById('valorinicial');
            var fee = document.getElementById('fee');
            var value = valorinicial.value;
            var number = parseFloat(value)*5/100;
            fee.value = number;
        });
    });
```